# PIG : load specific files from a folder

Tags: load, apache-pig

My load function should be sensitive to the age of files , I am interested in only files created in last 1 week and folder has files of 30 days in it.

I am relatively new to Pig and have seen custom loader which but haven't found an option to restrict files to be loaded.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Isn't there a pattern in the file name ? Something like file_1, file_2, .... ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to do this within Pig.  Use parameter substitution inside a Bash script. If running in Pig in local mode, you can use the `find` command to grab the files:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=/path/to/directory/of/input/files
pig -p input="{$(find $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -7 | tr '\n' ',')}" myscript.pig
```

- `find $DIR` locates all the files in `$DIR`.
- `-maxdepth 1 -type f` ensures that you will only consider regular
  files in the directory you specify (no sub-directories).
- `-mtime -7` restricts the listing to files modified in the last 7 days.
- `tr '\n' ','` turns it into a comma-separated list.

Then, in `myscript.pig`, you would have a statement like `data = LOAD '$input' AS (...);`

If you are running Pig on a cluster, you will need to use `hdfs dfs -ls` and do some parsing of the output to get the filenames.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My files count will be very high , it can be around 35k .I have to confirm if pi can take this many file names with comma separator .It might not be accepting the big list,  so wanted to check if any other options to achieve it .